# on button click add action url jquery

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a link like this:

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyphicon-color-red btn-delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" user-id="56f52ea551d72027711157d6"></a>
```

And with jquery, on click I take parameter `user-id` and I change action URL, this code isn't working cause when I click the delete button modal popup appears, but if I do inspect element I see that action is empty?

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function () {
  var user_id = $(this).attr('user-id');
  $('#modal-form').attr('action', "{{ url_for('admin.delete_user', id=" +user_id+" ) }}");
    });
```

The method that I use in route admin.delete_user in python is:

```
def delete_user(self, id):
    mongo.db.users.remove({'_id': ObjectId(id)})
    return redirect(url_for('admin.users'))
```

And the modal popup:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></h4>
    </div>
    <form id="modal-form" action=" "  method="POST">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Are you sure?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-style" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-filter-apply btn-style" >Yes</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why in jquery the action URL is not added?

Comment: What do you mean action is empty? is it empty when it's clicked or when it comes back from the server? Is it entirely empty or is it just missing the user_id part?

Comment: when I click on the a link with class .btn-delete, modal appears, I see the there  the modal action URL is totally empty, just like this"<form id="modal-form" action=" " method="POST">" , I'm thinking that the problem is when I pass the parameter user_id on url_for, but I'm not sure?

Comment: I think your jquery doesn't know what to do with {{ }}. What I would do is include that part in your form action, then just append the user_id to that in jquery

Comment: {{}} - is jinja syntax but how to do that , when url will be replaced?

Comment: The issue is that your server doesn't see the function call inside {{ }} before the jquery does so it can't replace it with the right string. you need to find a way to put the call somewhere the server can see it and pass the user_id to it later with js.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the DOM has loaded before you make any changes, for which you can use ready():

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your url_for function to to produce part of the url you need, then place it in the action attr. Then, use jquery to append the user_id to the string. Make sure you modify whatever is grabbing the url to parse a parameter. Here's an example:

url_for returns something like: http://www.example.com?delete_user=

Then your form action:

```
<form id="modal-form" action="{{url_for(delete_user)}}"  method="POST">
```

And your jquery would then:

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function () {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('user-id');
    var action = $('#modal-form').attr('action');
    $('#modal-form').attr('action', action + user_id);
});
```

Finally, whatever is parsing your form would look for the url parameter delete_user= and use the user_id you appended to it.